# list of lambda functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I need to create a list of lambda functions that would act on torch tensor. However the results are not returning what I expect. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

lb = list()
for i in range (2):
    lb.append(lambda Z: Z[...,1+i])

# to test
x = np.random.rand(10,3)
xt = torch.from_numpy(x)

print(lb[0](xt))
print(lb[1](xt))
```

This return the same results for both lambda functions. Which would be different if I simply do

```
lb = [lambda Z:Z[...,1], lambda Z:Z[...,2]]
```

Any suggestion on how I can do this with the for loop?
Thanks

Comment: You may find [this paragraph](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) useful.

Comment: many thanks @bereal That was exactly what I was after